# With React prop-types is it possible to validate on whether a string contains something?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a button component with a colour prop. Colour prop can be either 'primary', 'secondary' or a hex colour e.g '#0000ff'. Of course `colour: PropTypes.string` will do but ideally I need to check against random strings. Is something like below possible?

```
Button.propTypes = {
  colour: PropTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'secondary', PropTypes.string.includes('#')]),
};
```

Or a function to check that string is up to 7 characters long with first character being '#'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own validator.

See the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for more details.

---

```
Button.propTypes = {
  colour: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (props[propName] !== 'primary' &&
        props[propName] !== 'secondary' &&
        !/^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$/.test(props[propName])) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Must be a valid color code.'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing thanks. I just needed to wrap the function in oneOf() and it does what ii want. Cheers