# reference a prop type string inside a string - vue js

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, vue-props

How do you do this?

I need to use a prop in a string, and I thought you did that with `${}` but idk.

```
<MyComponent valueId="12345678" />
```

MyComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://app.com/apikey=12345qwerty&valueid=${valueId}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</template>
```

[Vuejs component props as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175527/vuejs-component-props-as-string)

this isn't quite it because this user is asking how to pass a prop as a string....not reference a prop in a string

I also tried

```
<template>
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://app.com/apikey=12345qwerty&valueid=[valueId]" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</template>
```

So when I google `reference a prop type string inside a string vue site stackoverflow.com` these are the results

[With React prop-types is it possible to validate on whether a string contains something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270004/with-react-prop-types-is-it-possible-to-validate-on-whether-a-string-contains-so)

[Other ways of showing prop-based conditonal text in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72241926/other-ways-of-showing-prop-based-conditonal-text-in-vue)

[Invalid Prop for Model Name, String Input presented as 'Undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479070/invalid-prop-for-model-name-string-input-presented-as-undefined)

sadly none of these answer my question.

How do you put a prop dynamically into a string?

ok i just tried

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
<template>
    <div>
        <iframe src=`https://app.com/apikey=12345qwerty&valueid=${valueId}` frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</template>
```

> 3:21   error  Parsing error:
> unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value  vue/no-parsing-error
> 3:76   error  Parsing error:
> unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value  vue/no-parsing-error
> 3:116  error  Parsing error:
> unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value  vue/no-parsing-error
> 3:129  error  Parsing error:
> unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value  vue/no-parsing-error
> 3:130  error  Parsing error:
> unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value  vue/no-parsing-error
>
> ✖ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)

Comment: You're looking for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic attribute, you need to insert a `:` before the attribute like `:src`, Also you can use template string `` to concatenate the `valueId` with the `URL`

```
<template>
<div>
    <iframe :src="`https://app.com/apikey=12345qwerty&valueid=${valueId}`" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing [`String interpolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) in the value of iframe `src` attribute, You have to delimited the whole value with backtick (`) characters. Please read this official documentation of [`Template literals`][2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Without template literals, when you want to combine output from expressions with strings, you'd concatenate them using the `"+"` (plus sign).

Hence, few suggestions as per your current code **:**

- If `valueId` will contains dynamic data. Then, pass it like `:valueId`.
- iframe `src` attribute value should be

  ```
  <iframe :src="`https://app.com/apikey=12345qwerty&valueid=${valueId}`"></iframe>
  ```